# How to find the REAL compile error in SwiftUI? (False error: Static member leading cannot be used on instance of type HorizontalAlignment)

Tags: swiftui

I'm struggling with SwiftUI and one of the biggest problems I run into is that it is constantly giving me error messages that have absolutely nothing to do with the problem. (I'll include an example below.) Do you have any suggestions for discovering the REAL error message so that I can stop wasting 10-20 minutes every time this happens commenting out large swathes of code until it finally tells me the problem?

For example, I was getting the compile error `Static member 'leading' cannot be used on instance of type 'HorizontalAlignment'` on the line `VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {`, but that's obviously wrong. Thankfully, I've figured out that whenever I see this error that it's really an error somewhere else... but do you have any recommendations for the easiest way to find the REAL error?

In this case, the real error was on the line `field: $data.pv`, because I had renamed the `.pv` field and so that variable was no longer a valid variable name.

```
struct EasyModeWhatIsLoanPayment: View {
    @ObservedObject private var data = DataWhatIsLoanPayment()

    var body: some View {
        NotepaperView {
            ScrollView {
                NotepaperView {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) { // <--- fake error reported here
                        QuestionAmount(
                            question: "What is the amount of your loan?",
                            field: $data.pv // <--- actual error was here
                        )
                        QuestionPercentage(
                            question: "What's the interest rate?",
                            valuedescription: "% Per Year",
                            field: $data.iyr
                        )
                        // ... more views
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("What is my Loan Payment?", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way to locate the correct error is to comment out bits of code and see what is going on. SwiftUI is still very new and the error messages are all over the place.